# Removing json parameter in jmeter if null value

Tags: jmeter

I have request like below, I will be passing dynamic values from a `csv` file

```java
"input":[
                {
                    "apiName":"Department",
                    "apiValue":["SUPPORT"],
                    "type":"MultiCheckBox",
                    "contains":false
                },
                {
                    "apiName":"Email",
                    "apiValue":[""],
                    "type":"email",
                    "contains":true
                }            
        ],
```

for above api value for  email is null, so the request should be below before running request, it should remove the null

```java
{
                    "apiName":"Department",
                    "apiValue":["SUPPORT"],
                    "type":"MultiCheckBox",
                    "contains":false
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request you want to parameterise
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).value = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()).input.findAll {item -> item.get('apiValue').get(0) != ''}).toPrettyString()
   ```
3. That's it, the PreProcessor will "scan" the request payload and remove all the JSON objects where `apiValue` is not set on the fly:

   [image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: once after running script {
  "input": [
 this part is also getting removed, I want output as below once after getting removed object{
  "input": [
    {
      "apiName": "Department",
      "apiValue": [
        "SUPPORT"
      ],
      "type": "MultiCheckBox",
      "contains": false
    }
  ]

}

Answer (score 0):

For:

```
{
                "apiName":"Email",
                "apiValue":[""],
                "type":"email",
                "contains":true
}
```

apiValue is NOT null. It is an array with an element "". For apiValue be null it has to be:

"apiValue" : null

You might like to use the filter function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

to get the array you need before making the request.